# Group vertical data for sums that will be used in division?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

My table looks like this:

```
Cell   Date      Hour    Minute    Counter   Value
AB1    20141008  14      15        C1        40
AB1    20141008  14      15        C2        15
AB1    20141008  14      30        C1        30
AB1    20141008  14      30        C2        13
```

I need to calculate formula PERCENT, which, if the data were horizontal and C1, C2 were columns, would look like this:

```
SELECT SUM(C2)/SUM(C1) as 'PERCENT'
FROM [Table]
group by Cell, Date, Hour
```

I was thinking of using OVER Clause, but I'm not sure how to implement it here.

In the case below, the result would be:

```
Cell   Date      Hour    PERCENT
AB1    20141008  14      0.40   (Total of C2 = 28 / Total of C1 = 70)
```

Thanks.

Comment: just post the output you want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*if the data were horizontal and C1, C2 were column*

You could PIVOT the data to make it so:

```
SELECT 
  Cell, Date, Hour, 
  SUM([C2])*100/SUM([C1]) AS [%],
  SUM([C2])/CAST(SUM([C1]) AS DECIMAL(10,5)) AS [Percent]
FROM TABLE1
PIVOT (SUM(value) FOR Counter in ([C1],[C2]) ) AS pvt
GROUP BY Cell, Date, Hour
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cc864/4)

Output:

```
| CELL |     DATE | HOUR |  % | PERCENT |
|------|----------|------|----|---------|
|  AB1 | 20141008 |   14 | 40 |     0.4 |
```

Comment: Lot easier to check this for div zero issue (if it is one.)

Comment: @Hogan Yeah, should be easy to prevent div zero; I didn't add it though.

Comment: Thanks for the post. How can I add the div zero condition within the `CAST` in the SELECT? I prefer not using `HAVING SUM([C1]) > 0`

Comment: So, if SUM([C1]) = 0 then the result will be 0 (no division will be done).

Comment: I added: `case when SUM(C1) > 0 then SUM(C2)/CAST(SUM(C1) AS DECIMAL(10,5)) end AS [Percent]`

Comment: @vmgmail Yeah that should do it.

Comment: @jpw, I know appreciation is against SO protocol and I'll probably be downvoted, but thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You do that like this:

```
SELECT Cell, Date, Hour,
   SUM(CASE WHEN Counter = 'C2' THEN Value ELSE 0 END) / 
   SUM(CASE WHEN Counter = 'C1' THEN Value ELSE 0 END) AS Percent
FROM [table]
group by Cell, Date, Hour
```

Comment: need to add ELSE as 1 to avoid divide by zero condition, incase C1 doesn't exists

Comment: @Rajesh - hmmm... not sure.  Poster did not say what to do in the div zero case.  I expect that situation will never happen.

Answer (score 1):

Use [CASE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) and try this

```
SELECT Cell,
       Date,
       Hour,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Counter = 'C1' THEN Value
           ELSE 0
           END )/
       SUM(CASE WHEN Counter = 'C2' THEN Value
           ELSE 0
           END) AS 'PERCENT'
FROM Table
GROUP BY Cell, Date, Hour
```

Comment: I'm interested to know why you posted exactly the same answer I posted.  Multiple answers which are the same is not useful.

Comment: @Hogan It's not quite the same as it is incorrect due to missing END in the case statements.

Comment: @Hogan I started the answer even before you posted and didn't see your answer when I posted this

Comment: @Srikanth - you are also grouping by Minute which is wrong.

Comment: @Hogan I wrote code with the original question in mind which didn't have expected output. Thanks for the suggestion will update it